# Polymer iron-select fires on element load

Tags: polymer-1.0

i have a paper-dropdown-menu inside a  repeating template, this dropdown have an on-iron-select event, problem is the event fires for each element being binded on the element load, how can i prevent this.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Status" required >
   <paper-menu selected="{{item.status}}" id="ddlStatus" attr-for-selected="value" on-iron-select="_statusChanged"  class="dropdown-content">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{statusList}}">
         <paper-item value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
      </template>
   </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling for hours i found a solution, which is not to use on-iron-select event and use on-iron-activate instead, this will only fires when an item is selected and will not fire while the drop-menu is being populated and default item set to it

Answer (score 1):

You solution will not work.`iron-activate` seems to be called when you open the selector and not on selecting a new option from the dropdown list.
Suppose, your current selected option was 'Status1' and you selected `Status2`. If you use `iron-select`, the value you'll get from `event.target.selected` is `Status2`. But,if you use `iron-activate`, you'll get the old selected value `Status1`.

Comment: Sorry,upvoted your answer. The mistake I was doing was to use `event.target.selected`. I needed `event.detail.selected`